# How can I model this problem?

Tags: panel-data, mixed-model, nonlinear, randomness

Genetic algorithms are a kind of evolutive approach to problem solving where solutions are randomly generated and crossed with each other as to produce other solutions.
With each generation or iteration of the algorithm the best individuals of the last generation (avaliated through a $fitness$ function) are kept (elitist selection) and  new individuals are generated through the imputation of crossovers and mutations on the previous generation individuals.
The best solution converges to optimal as the number of generations increases.

As any evolutionary algorithm that relies on diversity there's a great deal of randomness in the model, intial solutions are random, pairs of individuals are crossed randomly and even the individuals that pass between generations are randomly selected (tough higher quality individuals are more likely to be chosen).

The randomness that can be attributed to the problem resides both in the initial seed and algorithm parameterization.

What I pretend is to fine tune the probability of crossover (generation of offsprings) and mutation (random mutation on existing solution) as this parameters are very likely to influence the rate of convergence of the algorithm.

After some initial thought and research I think what I am looking for is a mixed model, since I want to examine longitudinal data (balanced).

After data collection here's my data behavior with some fixed parameters for 50 simulations:
 [image]
Apart from variation there actually seems be a pattern. How should I model my problem? Is this a mixed model problem? Is there a way to compare the behaviour of all the mixed models (one for each parameterization) as to find the set of parameters that more rapidly come to a solution?

Should I use a mixed effects model to finetune the coefficients for:

$f(x,\rho_1, \rho_2, \rho_3) = \frac{\rho_1}{x+\rho_2}+\rho_3$

Where $\rho_1$, $\rho_2$ and $\rho_3$ are hyper-parameters to fit the model to the curve, and after that compare the $\rho_1$ parameters as they model rate at which the function converges to $\rho_3$ (global minimum).

**EDIT:**
I tried to do as proposed, I fitted a non linear mixed model to my data. Here's the outcome, blue lines represent individual longitudinal data fitted to the above mentioned function and the green line the outcome of the mixed model as described by the found parameters. I might have no idea of what I'm doing, so comments are highly appreciated.

Also, I assumed $\rho_1$, $\rho_2$ and $\rho_3$ as random effects, has the initial setup as randomness associated, the convergence ratio has a lot of variance and the final solution might be good but not optimal.

[image]
Here's the ouput of the mixed model.

```
Nonlinear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['nlmerMod']
Formula: BestFitness ~ minimizeGradient(Generation, a, b, c) ~ (b | Simulation) +      (a | Simulation) + (c | Simulation)
   Data: dataset

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 49592.5  49634.5 -24789.2  49578.5     2993 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.4286 -0.5915  0.0492  0.6050  5.1083 

Random effects:
 Groups       Name Variance Std.Dev.
 Simulation   b           0    0.0  
 Simulation.1 a    41242716 6422.0  
 Simulation.2 c      814576  902.5  
 Residual            730543  854.7  
Number of obs: 3000, groups:  Simulation, 100

Fixed effects:
   Estimate Std. Error t value
a 6.382e+04  1.123e+03   56.84
b 2.390e+00  4.962e-02   48.16
c 2.377e+03  1.015e+02   23.42

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
  a      b     
b  0.789       
c -0.346 -0.382
```

Thanks for your time.